# echo only location Twitter GET API

Tags: php, twitter, foreach, echo

I would like to echo the list of the location of the followers of a given account on Twitter. The result I get for the moment is the following:

```
Array
(
[users] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2247341036
                [id_str] => 2247341036
                [name] => Niall Horan
                [screen_name] => srthoranpayne
                [location] => london      biben
                [description] => My dreams come true
                [url] => 
                [entities] => Array
                    (
                        [description] => Array
                            (
                                [urls] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [protected] => 
                [followers_count] => 325
                [friends_count] => 641
                [listed_count] => 0
                [created_at] => Sun Dec 15 15:10:06 +0000 2013
                [favourites_count] => 63
                [utc_offset] => 
                [time_zone] => 
                [geo_enabled] => 
                [verified] => 
                [statuses_count] => 223
                [lang] => es
                [status] => Array

 [etc etc]
```

But I would like to have only

```
                [location] => london      biben
```

Can anyone help me on the code I would have to add after this? I think it is something with the loop "foreach", but I don't know how to put it. How should I modify the last lines?

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
$getfield = '?screen_name='.$visitor.'&count=200';


$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3>        <p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."    </em></p>";exit();}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
echo $string[user]["location"];*/
foreach($string as $items)
  {
   echo "Tweeted by: ".$['user']['location']."<br />";
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I added the last lines of code I have already tried without success.

EDIT Below: Current code.

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
else {$user  = "$visitor";};
$getfield = '?screen_name='.$visitor.'&count=200';


$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3>                <p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."        </em></p>";exit();}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
 foreach($data as $items)
  {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    echo "Location: " . $items[$i]['location']. "<br />";
   }
  }
```

Comment: echo $string[0]["location"];

Comment: Thanks @Skewled. Actually, there are several users, so not only [0]. I also added the solution I tried at the end of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You loop over the result like so:

```
foreach($string as $items)
  {
   echo "Tweeted by: " . $items[0]['location'] . "<br />";
  }
```

EDIT:

Here is a more robust example:

```
$data = Array
    (
    "users" => Array
        (
            "0" => Array
                (
                    "id" => "2247341036",
                    "id_str" => "2247341036",
                    "name" => "Niall Horan",
                    "screen_name" => "srthoranpayne",
                    "location" => "london      biben",
                    "description" => "My dreams come true",
                    "url" => "",
                    "entities" => Array
                        (
                            "description" => Array
                                (
                                    "urls" => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        ),

                    "protected" => "",
                    "followers_count" => "325",
                    "friends_count" => "641",
                    "listed_count" => "0",
                    "created_at" => "Sun Dec 15 15:10:06 +0000 2013",
                    "favourites_count" => "63",
                    "utc_offset" => "",
                    "time_zone" => "",
                    "geo_enabled" => "",
                    "verified" => "",
                    "statuses_count" => "223",
                    "lang" => "es",
                    "status" => Array ()
                ),
            "1" => Array
                (
                    "id" => "2247341036",
                    "id_str" => "2247341036",
                    "name" => "Niall Horan",
                    "screen_name" => "srthoranpayne",
                    "location" => "berlin germany",
                    "description" => "My dreams come true",
                    "url" => "",
                    "entities" => Array
                        (
                            "description" => Array
                                (
                                    "urls" => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        ),

                    "protected" => "",
                    "followers_count" => "325",
                    "friends_count" => "641",
                    "listed_count" => "0",
                    "created_at" => "Sun Dec 15 15:10:06 +0000 2013",
                    "favourites_count" => "63",
                    "utc_offset" => "",
                    "time_zone" => "",
                    "geo_enabled" => "",
                    "verified" => "",
                    "statuses_count" => "223",
                    "lang" => "es",
                    "status" => Array ()
                )               
            )
        );

  foreach($data as $items)
  {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    echo "Tweeted by: " . $items[$i]['location']. "<br />";
   }
  }
```

OUTPUTS:

```
Location: london biben
Location: berlin germany
```

**EDIT:** I was probably not very clear but you have to mix a foreach and for loop to get the results you want:

```
  foreach($data as $items)
  {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    echo "Location: " . $items[$i]['location']. "<br />";
   }
  }
```

Now you will advance in the array and get the output you wanted. (:

Comment: This nearly works, but I got this result, which probably means that I should go further down the tree:
Tweeted by: 
Tweeted by: 
Tweeted by: 1
Tweeted by: 
Tweeted by: 0

Comment: It loops over the $string array and gets the location, I will test it on my laptop shortly.

Comment: @Jonas please look at the answer again, I updated it with a full working example for you.

Comment: Thank you very much again Skewled. It still doesn't work. Maybe it is because I have one more level in my tree, compared to what you put in your example ? I have 

Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2468887874
                    [id_str] => 2468887874
                    [name] => Tatiana Andrarde
                    [screen_name] => Tatianaandradeo
                    [location] => 
etc

Comment: @Jonas I modified the answer again, this time it should work with the exact array you have. I just closed out the array from your example and modified it so I could use it in a test case.

Comment: Thank you again @Skewled, and sorry for answering late. Unfortunately I still couldn't make it work. Will try again and write if I find a solution.

Comment: @Jonas Please see my new edit, I was trying to help you figure it out and learn but I was not being clear enough so I will just show you how it's done using a foreach with a for loop.

Comment: @Jonas can you please let me know if this solved your issue, ty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your patience. Still not working. I paste my current code below my question, so maybe you will figure why it's not?

Comment: @Jonas `print_r($string);
 foreach($data as $items)` you are using $string to hold the array of data, you have to change the foreach `foreach($string as $items)`

Comment: Still not working... I probably have to check this live with a php expert.

Comment: Sorry I'm just not sure why your having issues, I tested this and it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, me neither... That's why I will try to see this live with somebody.